# searchkick to show only with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently working on a Customer Management System. I am using searchkick to search customers from my customers table. What i am trying to do is to limit the search for each user to only be able to search within their own customer list. Each customer has their own user_id column and i would like searchkick to only search within the users own customers with his/her user_id.

This is my customer_controller.html.erb

```
def index
  @customers = Customer.search(params.fetch(:q, "*"),
  order: {name: :asc})
end
```

can anyone help me? thanks so much!

Comment: So you have where clause for searchkick, right? From doc - `Product.search "apples", where: {in_stock: true}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding the customer first before doing the search, so something like:

```
def index
  @customer = Customer.find_by(params[:id])
  @customers = Customer.search(params.fetch(:q, "*"),
  order: {name: :asc})
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out by adding the code:

```
where: {user_id: current_user.id})
```

into the controller

Thanks to all that tried to help!